# Heroku app with Yahoo! hosted domain SSL

Tags: ssl, heroku, yahoo

I have a Heroku app that I would like to access via a subdomain of a client's Yahoo hosted domain through https (SSL).  I have set up the subdomain on the Yahoo side via a DNS CNAME entry and the forwarding works fine to the Heroku app -- albeit with a certificate warning.

**Question**: do I have to purchase the SLL certificate for the subdomain to be installed on Heroku from Yahoo?

**Update**: Here are the SSL Endpoint instructions on Heroku: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no.  I am adding this sentence to meet the minimum answer length requirement.